# Generics "New" constraint equivalent in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript

In C#, you can do:

```
class ItemFactory<T> where T : new()
{
    public T GetNewItem()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

In typescript, the closest I've managed to achieve is:

```
class ItemFactory<T>{
  instantiatibleModel : new() => T;

  constructor(modelWithctor : { new(): T }){
    this.instantiatibleModel = modelWithctor;
  }


  GetNewItem() : T{
     return new this.instantiatibleModel();
   }
}
```

Any ideas how I can get it cleaner/closer to C# syntax?

Comment: Since generic information is all removed during compilation, there can't be a solution that only uses generic parameters.

Comment: @recursive Is there any way to force it through an interface instead, for example IMustHaveConstructor (though then I think we are going to fall into the interfaces-can't-force-constructors hole)

Comment: Additionally, could you explain - if generic information is removed during compilation, what is the `{ new(): T }` syntax doing?

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-cant-i-write-typeof-t-new-t-or-instanceof-t-in-my-generic-function

Comment: @David: `{ new(): T }` is called a "construct signature".  See [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces-class-types).  Basically, it's an interface that specifies that implementing type has a matching constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this to work for all classes? If you have a super base class, it can be done in a simple way.

```
class Base {
    hi() {
        alert('base');
    }
}
class Derived extends Base {
    hi() {
        alert('Der');
    }
}
class Gen<T extends Base >{
    constructor(private testType) {
    }
 create<T>(): T { 
    return new this.testType();
 }
}
var g=new Gen<Derived>(Derived);
var obj= g.create();
```