# How to specify the type for any class which implements an abstract class?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to specify a type for “any class which implements this abstract class”?

For example:

```js
// LIBRARY CODE
abstract class Table {
  static readonly tableName: string;
}
type TableConstructor = typeof Table;
// type TableConstructor = (new (...args: never) => Table);
const createORM = (tables: Array<TableConstructor>) => {
  return {
      executeQuery() {
        // What type should the "tables" array be
        // to support both of the next two lines
        console.log(tables[0].tableName)
        return new tables[0]();
        //     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        // Cannot create an instance of an abstract class
      }
  }
}


// EXAMPLE USER CODE
class Foo implements Table {
  static get tableName() {
      return 'foo';
  }
}
const orm = createORM([Foo]);
```

[TypeScript Playground Example Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBkEkCECUEFYE1QGEDyARAogKAIYBGAzgC4BO+AxqaFQDb7HGgAqR9ApqAN66igy+UgEsqocp3wATAPYA7egE9QpDpwBy+ALacAXIIoj5AcwDcuAL65SSgA7d2hLqgVlyAVxqzyoALyq9pyyAGZs6hYggQ7hzpyu8u5epD7+oAAU8pwA7hkAdAX45CbEBlkAbpzkAJT+AHyxXNUWVG60VJLCnOiwALJp6WpxpaDw5JRKADxOLm2e3uR1tX4NfAKSpB7k8rz8AvucAB6cVB6knACKHlVK6bVr+49RAOoAFsLR3MSvsh700qpXtwAERDLjEYGgIoTUCETh7R4CKIpQQeOx2Hy0QiyUivUChQHcLKHWikbKyUD0YycYgIxGtRKyLh5eiyEyDdTEADaAAYALp5MGaHScap0x4bLY7LK5IXc-l3CyI-ZRR4APw1mq12rV4pVYFQ+Hk8hxdE65yhO2MQnkVG4BKNUJIFGo7UYzD11gE1msuFwUWwAA14L0AArgbCgACqAGVsLA0Fg8AwmCwAGKyCkibR2Li6eSkFgzbgPISicQmTik9RaXR3XbKyXbUAAchCmZbStAPtwDLI+PI2jSHSk5x6vXSXIzsj5zSAA)

Comment: I think you need to use generic and look here, for example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298915/generics-new-constraint-equivalent-in-typescript

Answer (score 1):

```
type TableConstructor = {
  new (...args: never): Table
  readonly tableName: string;
};
```

or even

```
type TableConstructor = (new (...args: never) => Table) & Omit<typeof Table, never>;
```

[Here is the example with this implementation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBkEkCECUEFYE1QGEDyARAogKAIYBGAzgC4BO%20AxqaFQDb7HGgAqR9ApqAN66igy%20UgEsqocp3wATAPYA7egE9QpDpwBy%20ALacAXIIoj5AcwDcuAL64QqpQAdu7Ql1QKy5AK41Z5UAF47R1kAMzZ1C1tSByd1N3kPb1JfANAACnlOAHd0gDp8-HITYgNMgDdOcgBKAIA%20cJdOKotoxwbXdwoklMCM7LyCopLQcsqa-3rnLhqAMlB0bRFSAB5WzlD2zgAaEc4K8lqLKk66SWFOdFgAWVS0tUbh%20HJKJWWpznjEnwPx%20r4BSSkTzkeS8fgCCGcAAenConlInAAip5Kko0jV-hCsbYAOoAC2EQW4xDxsk89Gkqjx3AARPcuMQaaBCi9QIROOCsQIorJBJ57PZfLRCLJSHjQBsxdxMlDaKQsrz6MZOMROVzjglZFxcvRZCY7upiABtAAMAF1cvTNDommqsYDgaDMjkrcbzeiLFzQNYBNZrLgbGBsAANeBXAAK4GwoAAqgBlbCwNBYPAMJgsABisl5Im09i4unkpBY7zBAiEonEJk4cvUWl06LLXIdINAAHIQtm257vVZcBqyBLyNpUlQzgjLlc0kas7Izc0gA)

Helpfully answered on the TypeScript discord: https://discord.com/channels/508357248330760243/968152049973874718/968163618401173564